# Cannot connect to network drive attached to Wifi router on Macbook Pro 2017, Mojave OS

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mojave, smb, ftp

I can see the network drive displayed in the finder but when I click on it keeps loading until freezes. Sometimes is working however. I can access the drive from Apple TV, Windows notebook and so.

Any solution?

Thank you for your help!

Best wishes

Comment: How exactly are you attempting to connect; SMB or FTP?   Those are very different protocols.  AppleTV and Windows defaults to SMB, are you using that?

Comment: Yes. Once I open the finder It appears on the left under "Network". I can see the network drive however when I try to open it keeps loading and loading. Then it freezes eventually and whole finder is stuck. I also tried Finder -> connect to server : smb address, however is not working. - Same address is working on Windows 10 without any problem)